# Repository level notification setting in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-deployment

I have a project in Azure DevOps with two repositories like one is for front end another one for backend application.

Both repositories have different developers assigned and their pipeline to build the repo.

I want to create a notification subscription on the repository level so if there is any build error happen with the front end repository then only UI developers should get notified instead of all users of the project.

I have not found any options in azure DevOps where I can create any notification subscription on repository level.

Any help will be a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have not found any options in azure DevOps where I can create any
>   notification subscription on repository level.

For now, notifications option in Azure Devops Service only support `Organization Level` and `Project Level` instead of `repository level`. So I'm afraid the option you're looking for is **not supported**.

Since it's one good idea, you can suggest a feature [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) in Azure Devops's User Voice forum, then the team would consider about your idea about Repos-level notifications. Hope it helps to resolve your puzzle :)

Comment: Sure I will do that.

Comment: After raising the suggestion. feel free to share the link here so that members interested in it can vote for you. Just a reminder :)

Comment: Posted ! -https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/997120/repository-level-notification-setting-in-azure-dev.html